Pwa standalone ios safari audio record
Does anyone have an idea on how to record audio in iOS iPhone PWA standalone mode? I'm facing an issue where my PWA works well on Safari, but when I add it to the home screen in standalone mode, it asks for permission to access audio. I grant permission, but the audio is not recorded; it just produces a beep sound. Does anyone know how to fix this?
I use this package link
I have a custom audio recording hook implemented. The issue arises in Safari when installing the PWA in standalone mode; it doesn't record audio despite prompting for permission. After conducting some research and development, I discovered that Safari, within a separate WebKit view, doesn't allow audio and video permissions.


import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const useAudioRecorder = (fn) => {
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = useState(null);
  const [, setAudioChunks] = useState([]);
  const [audioUrl, setAudioUrl] = useState('');
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);

  const mediaStreamRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRecording) {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
          setMediaRecorder(recorder);
          mediaStreamRef.current = stream;
          const chunks = [];
          recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
            chunks.push(event.data);
          };
          recorder.onstop = () => {
            const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });
            fn(blob);
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            setAudioUrl(url);
          };
          recorder.start();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
          setHasPermission(false); // Set permission state to false
        });
    } else if (mediaRecorder) {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      mediaStreamRef.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      setMediaRecorder(null);
      setHasPermission(false);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isRecording]);

  const startRecording = () => {
    setIsRecording(true);
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    setIsRecording(false);
  };

  const clearRecording = () => {
    setAudioChunks([]);
    setAudioUrl('');
  };

  const resetRecorder = () => {
    setAudioChunks([]);
    setAudioUrl('');
    setIsRecording(false);
    setMediaRecorder(null);
  };
  return {
    isRecording,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording,
    clearRecording,
    audioUrl,
    resetRecorder,
    hasPermission,
  };
};

export default useAudioRecorder;



Thanks,
Usama

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
